# JsonApiDotNetCore 5.0.1 Breaks with latest version of Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.3.0)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, json-api

We are developing a rich REST Api using the very nice JsonApiDotNetCore library (5.0.1).
We have many dozens of APIs working just fine.

However, today I updated my VS 2022 to 17.3.0, and now when I try to run I get
the error JsonApiDotNetCore.Errors.InvalidConfigurationException with the message "Multiple controllers found for resource type ...

Running the same source on a non-updated VS2022 works just fine.

Any clues out there?

Comment: The stack trace of where it fails:

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the JsonApiDotNetCore dev team, especially bkoelman, he responded with a bunch of info on the github [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore/issues/1179)  In our case, we needed to have a scaffold controller, due to requirements in our app for attributes supporting security.  We were also using the [Resource] attribute on our controller scaffold.  The Resource tag was generating the full controllers therefore our scaffold was producing the error.  I guess this is a known bug in the .Net Core 6 SDK.   The fix was to remove the [Resource] attribute.